# How give space text in math mode?

Tags: math-mode, spacing

I have a problem about space text in math mode , and i have minimal working anwers like this following from Microsoft Word :
[image: with space in Microsoft Word]

But, since i use LaTeX dont space text in math mode, like this following from LaTeX result :
[image: not space in LaTeX result]

How give space text math mode in LaTeX ?
I use code LaTeX like this

```
\begin{tabular}{lll}

$Biaya total_{kincir angin}$&=&40 $\times$ Rp 60.000.000,00\\
                          &=&  Rp 2.400.000.000,00
\end{tabular}

and

 \begin{tabular}{lll}

$Biaya total_{kincir angin}$&=& 3000 $\times$ Rp 5.000.000,00\\
                            &=& Rp 15.000.000.000,00
\end{tabular}
```

Comment: Checkout the section on math mode spacing:  crab.rutgers.edu/~karel/latex/class5/class5.html

Comment: Oke, successfull, @rickhg12hs thank

Comment: Down-voted, because a simple search on Google using a combination of “LaTeX”, “math”, and “spacing” (or alternatively “text”) generates answers to the OPs question in the first 10 hits.

Furthermore, if you want to write out actual words n math mode, use `\text{}`.

Comment: Ok, @mSSM , thank for your vote , sorry , i'm a beginner in LaTeX

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt]{standalone}% change it back to your own document class
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[
    group-separator=.,
    output-decimal-marker={,},
]{siunitx}

\def\dummy{%
Karl's students do not care about dashing patterns. 
Karl's students do not care about arrow tips. 
Karl's students, by the way, do not know what a transformation matrix is.}

\begin{document}
\dummy
\begin{align*}
\text{Biaya Total}_{\,\text{kincir angin}}
    &= 40 \times \SI{60000000.00}[Rp\,]{}\\
    &= \SI{2400000000.00}[Rp\,]{}
\end{align*}
\dummy
\end{document}
```

[image]

### Remarks:

- always specify your decimal numbers with a period as the decimal marker.
- always use `siunit` when specifying numbers such that you can change the setting globally.
- `group-separator=.` makes the input `123456` get rendered as `123.456`.
- `output-decimal-marker={,}` makes the input `12.23` get rendered as `12,45`.
- Combining both `group-separator=.,output-decimam-marker={,}` makes the input `123456.78` get rendered as `123.456,78`.
- use `align*` to vertically align the `=`s and to remove the equation numbers.
- use `\text` in math mode to make texts get rendered as normal texts.

Answer (score 10):

The math italic font is not designed to make multi-letter words, the letters are widely spaced to producing spacing fro individual identifiers.  Use

```
\textit{Biaya total}_{\textit{kincir angin}}
```

Together with the `amsmath` package so that the `\text...` commands produce smaller fonts

Comment: Thank your for all your answer and i have the result and succesfull from rickhg12hs and user32411 , and thank for Mr David for more completely your Anwers.